# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un script de Python desde la consola de Linux si estoy en otro directorio?

Tags: python, linux, bash

Tengo un script Python con una función, la cual quiero invocar desde la consola Linux.

Pero hasta el momento solo puedo llamarla si lo ejecuto desde el mismo directorio pero no desde otro.

Comando Bash:

```
python -c 'import checkInternet; print checkInternet.internet_on()
```

Script Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2
import sys
import os

def internet_on():
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen('http://216.58.192.142', timeout=1)
        return True
    except urllib2.URLError as err:
        return False
        #os.system('/etc/init.d/network reload')
        os.system('reset-mcu')
```

Comment: Bienvenido Eduardo, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y siempre es útil repasar [ask]. Con respecto tu pregunta, efectivamente es lógico este comportamiento, cuando haces `import checkInternet`, python va a buscar `checkInternet.py` en la carpeta actual. Por que simplemente no haces que el Script imprima el resultado e invocas `python ruta_al_script/checkInternet.py`? Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siendo estrictos, no ejecutas un *script*. Ese fichero que ejecutas mediante *import* es técnicamente un **módulo**. Y, como todos los módulos, python tiene que saber dónde encontrarlos, o sea, tiene que estar en algunas de las rutas de `sys.path`.

Por defecto, python incluye el directorio de trabajo entre las rutas donde buscar módulos. De este modo, cuando ejecutas un script, se incluye el directorio del script para tener así localizados los módulos que le acompañan.

Pero, en tu caso, el módulo no está en el directorio de trabajo. Python no sabe dónde encontrarlo. La solución está en incluir el directorio del módulo entre los directorios de búsqueda. Hay varias formas de hacerlo, pero la manera más fácil sería usando la variable de entorno `PYTHONPATH`:

```sh
$ PYTHONPATH="directorio/del/script" python -c 'import checkInternet; print checkInternet.internet_on()'
```

Comment: Interesante, buena respuesta.

Comment: Excelente ya me quedo muy claro, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente lo más práctico y sano sea ir directamenta a ese directorio y una vez allí ejecutarlo:

```
cd directorio/del/script.py && python -c 'import checkInternet; print checkInternet.internet_on()
```

Si no quieres acabar después en otro directorio, puedes añadir `&& cd -` para volver al directorio donde estabas, o bien ejecutarlo en una subshell:

```
( cd directorio/del/script.py && python -c 'import checkInternet; print checkInternet.internet_on() (
```